# GTKMM : sigc++/sigc++.h - File doesn't exist

Tags: compiling

I've searched askubuntu about this error and of course many people do encounter compilation in GTKMM but mine is a different case. I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to compile a blank GTK window.

I sudo rm -rf /usr/include/sigc++-2.0 (Despite I know what will happen if I make a mistake) and built libsigc++ again. Still, same error. Then I sudo rm -rf it again and built from source the latest version of sigc++. Still, same error. And I think ask ubuntu is my last resort.

This is what I entered:

```
g++ base.cc -o base `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

The character before the 'p' in 'pkg-config' and the last character after '--libs' are backticks and not single quotes.

I was expecting a successfully compiled program. But instead, I got this:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:87:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87,
                 from base.cc:1:
/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:58:27: fatal error: sigc++/sigc++.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Now I'm pretty much stressed out and tommorow is school!

Comment: When you built sigc++ from source, where did you install it *to*? Most source packages install to `/usr/local` by default - if that's the case here also you will likely need to add `-I /usr/local/include` in order for `g++` to locate the header. A similar step may be required for the library path i.e. `-L /usr/local/lib`. BTW why are you not able to use the pre-built `libsigc++-2.0-dev` package for this?

Comment: @steeldriver actually installed it twice after I checked it just now, it's installed in `/usr/local/include/`  and in `/usr/include/` if I remove the one that is installed in `/usr/include/` with sudo rm -rf, will it work? (I know that's a dangerous thing to do).

Comment: If the files in `/usr/include` belong to a package that was installed via apt, then really you should *uninstall* them using apt e.g. `apt-get remove --purge libsigc++-2.0-dev`

Comment: @steeldriver OK, I removed it and still, same thing. No change to the error output.

Comment: Did you add the `-I` directive?

Comment: @steeldriver You mean when I was going to sudo rm -rf it? or when I build it?